# Applying Scikit-Learn Linear Kernel with a generator for low memory pressure

Tags: python, memory-management, numpy, scipy

```
matrix = # a sparse matrix of TFIDF vectors - 28458x3218988
```

My aim was to create a similarity matrix comparing all documents to all documents using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` but the doc notes indicated that with normalized values, such as TFIDF vectors, that `linear_kernel' was equivalent with better performance.

I tried `linear_kernel(matrix,matrix)` which I believe is valid but was clearly going to take a long time and was resulting in high memory pressure. My solution which uses a generator and writing to disk to alleviate memory pressure, functions, but I wondered if there was any way to speed it up.

```
def cos_compare(corpus_matrix):
    for i in range(0, corpus_matrix.shape[0]):
        x = linear_kernel(corpus_matrix[i],corpus_matrix)
        yield i,x
```

My generator `cos_compare` iterates through the matrix row by row, yielding the index  and the result of applying linear kernel to measure the similarity between document at index `i` and all documents.

```
try:
    with open('cosine_data.csv','a') as f:
        for i,x in cos_compare(matrix):
            if i%100 == 0:
                print('Saving Row {} of {}:'.format(i, matrix.shape[0]))
            pd.DataFrame(x).to_csv(f, header=False,index=False,mode='a')

finally:
    cosine_data = pd.read_csv('cosine_data.csv', header=None)
    print(cosine_data.head())
```

The script opens `'cosine_data.csv'` for appending and then initializes `cos_compare()` generator. The single row array that the generator yields as `x` is then converted to a pandas `DataFrame` for convenience when writing a line to disk (`np.savetxt()` was throwing format errors).

Currently works fine but am I overlooking any optimizations from `numpy`,`pandas` or `scikit` that I could use?

Comment: I am looking for a good solution to this small problem too. I found a doc that may enlighten you a little bit: https://medium.com/@AgenceSkoli/how-to-avoid-memory-overloads-using-scikit-learn-f5eb911ae66c

Comment: BTW, the solution you mention runs quite slow. I think it is because the frequent I/O R/W because you use "append". A possible solution could be to use bulk dot product instead of iterating line by line.

Comment: Hi Z.Wei thanks for the input. That article was interesting. I'd also be interested to see an implementation using bulk dot product as you suggest as I don't think I fully understand what this would look like. If you have the time please do add an answer.